# jQuery File Upload - Not showing the uploaded files after reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

So, I have been trying to figure this out for the past three hours, and I feel like I am nowhere close to getting it ... . Any help would be appreciated.

I have been able to set the **jQuery File Uploader** to save the uploaded images in a dynamic path/url. All seems to work, and the files are uploaded in the right places and show up on frontend. But, once reloaded the page, there is no sign of them. Obviously, it's path/directory url error. I just can't figure out what!

Here is my HTML file on *http://127.0.0.1/local/platform/backend/page-edit.php*

```
<form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ...
   <input type="hidden" name="path" value="products"><!-- Setting the directory to save the img -->
   ...
</form>
```

JFU's PHP files UploadHandler.php and index.php are under *http://127.0.0.1/local/platform/uploads/*
index.php:

```
$options = array('upload_dir'=>$_POST['path'].'/'.date("Y").'/'.date("n").'/', 'upload_url'=>'../uploads/'.$_POST['path'].'/'.date("Y").'/'.date("n").'/');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
```

main.js under *http://127.0.0.1/local/platform/backend/plugins/jQuery-File-Upload-9.5.7/js/*

```
$(function () {
'use strict';
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: '../uploads/'
});
...
});
```

As I said, the files upload and appear right. But when I refresh the page, they no longer appear in the table ... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!

Basically, I am assigning the values I want as JS variables in the footer. I, then, use the variables that have the data I need on main.js like this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
   url: '.../uploads/index.php?page_type=' + THE_VARIABLE
});
```

Now, the data is passed to the index.php file under my **uploads** directory. So, I get the query string and send it to the UploadHandler.php:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query_string);
$options('upload_dir'=>$query_string['page_type'], 'upload_url'=>'../uploads/'.$query_string['page_type']);
...
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($potions);
```

Boom! Works like a charm!